# Cancel the POST when the page is refreshed

Tags: python, django, post

My problem is: when an user refresh a form, the data in the `Form` is sent.

I have a `Form` with a `POST` request.

The user writes his name, mail and a message. If the mail is correct, the message is sent.

In my view, if the `Form` is valid, I add the message in my model Message.

After that I disable the "Send" button. But if the user refreshes the page, my view is called, and another row is added in my model.

I would like, when the user refreshes the page, to block the POST.

My View:

```
def contact(request):

    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid(): 
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']

        new_message = Message()
        new_message.name = name
        new_message.message = message
        new_message.mail = mail
        new_message.save()

        envoi = True

    return render(request, 'vautmieux/contact.html', locals())
```

My URL:

```
path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="{% url "contact" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              {{ form.name }}
              {{ form.mail }}
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6" >
              {{ form.message }}
           </div>
           <button id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">ENVOYER LE MESSAGE !</button>
        </div>
    {% if envoi %}Votre message a bien été envoyé !{% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main reason why people implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). In case of a *successful* POST request, you should return a redirect to a URL. As a result the browser will perform a GET, and in case the browser thus performs a refresh later, it will make a GET again.

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            return redirect('some-message-successful-view')
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
    return render(request, 'vautmieux/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Here *`'some-message-successful-view'`* needs to be replaced with the name of a view you trigger when sending a message was succesful. This can be the same view as the one defined here. I advice to use [*Django's message framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to send a message to the user that the message has been submitted successfully.